# VSCode Close window shortcut (cmd + w) doesn't work after turning on Shortcut Sync

Tags: visual-studio-code

I always used the default `cmd + w` shortcut for closing a window (or rather a tab) in the vscode editor.

After I turned on Shortcut Sync via my Github profile this particular shortcut stopped working although I didn't overwrite any settings.

This is my keybindings.json in the user folder:

```
// Place your key bindings in this file to override the defaults
[
  {
    "key": "cmd+left",
    "command": "workbench.action.navigateBack",
    "when": "canNavigateBack"
  },
  {
    "key": "ctrl+left",
    "command": "-workbench.action.navigateBack",
    "when": "canNavigateBack"
  },
  {
    "key": "cmd+right",
    "command": "workbench.action.navigateForward",
    "when": "canNavigateForward"
  },
  {
    "key": "ctrl+right",
    "command": "-workbench.action.navigateForward",
    "when": "canNavigateForward"
  },
  {
    "key": "cmd+w cmd+r",
    "command": "editor.emmet.action.wrapWithAbbreviation",
  }
]
```

And here is an excerpt of my default keyboard shortcut settings:

```
{ "key": "cmd+w",                 "command": "workbench.action.closeActiveEditor" },
{ "key": "cmd+w",                 "command": "workbench.action.closeGroup",
                                     "when": "activeEditorGroupEmpty && multipleEditorGroups" },
{ "key": "cmd+w",                 "command": "workbench.action.closeWindow",
```

What could be wrong with my shortcut settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do have conflicting shortcuts. Unfortunately vscode doesn't warn you of conflicts when you merge your settings after turning on Sync.

Your `wrapWithAbbreviation` `cmd+w cmd+r` shortcut conflicts with your default `cmd+w` shortcuts because both rely on the `cmd+w` combination. So vscode is always waiting for further input once you pressed `cmd+w` and never executes the `closeWindow` shortcut.

To resolve this, modify the context (`when`) in which you want to use your custom `wrapWithAbbreviation` shortcut. Typically you use it after selecting text.
Here is the correct command:

```
{
"key": "cmd+w cmd+r",
"command": "editor.emmet.action.wrapWithAbbreviation",
"when": "editorHasSelection"
}
```

For all the other contexts (and logical operators), take a look at the [vscode documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/when-clause-contexts#available-contexts).

I hope this helps!